# two ajax links fire the same controller action in YII

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

In my view I want to be able to delete and update my listview with ajax. Now, both links work right if the other one is not there. If they're both there, the both fire the `actionUpdate`. Does anyone know why the delete action isn't fired anymore ?

```
    <div class="delete">
    <?php
    echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
        '<img src="handig/ikoons/delete.png" width="20"/>',
        array("plaatjes/delete","id"=>$data->id),
        array(
            "beforeSend" => "js:function(){ return confirm('Confirm ?') }",
            "success"=>'js:function(data){ $.fn.yiiListView.update("post_list"); }',
            "type"=>"post",
        ),
        array("id"=>$data->id)
    ); ?>              
    </div>

    <div class="edit">
    <?php
    echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
        '<img src="handig/ikoons/edit.png" width="20"/>',
        array("plaatjes/update","id"=>$data->id, "pad"=>$data->pad),
        array(
            'data'=>array('Plaatjes'=>'data'),
            "success"=>'js:function(data){ $.fn.yiiListView.update("post_list"); }',
            "type"=>"post",
        ),
        array("id"=>$data->id)
    ); ?>              
    </div>
```

Comment: did you get any confirm prompt while click delete link?

Comment: if the delete class is alone, I get the confirm prompt. In the situation as above, with both links there I don't get anything. 
If I check the debugger, I can see it fires the controller 'plaatjes/update'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem on your HTMLOptions array .
You are duplicate the ID

```
array("id"=>$data->id)
```

on both links . change or remove this

Comment: well, they both need the id to handle the right item. So it wouldn't work if i removed that.

Comment: @Daniel, Ryan is correct. Remove the last `array("id"=>$data->id)` from both links, the one just before the closing `); ?></div>`.

Comment: @Daniel You don't need the 4th parameter of `ajaxLink()`, duplicate ids in HTML will cause JavaScript to only select the first one. Also, if I'm not wrong, Yii will set a dynamic HTML id attribute for that, which you are overriding with the 4th parameter. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail